# get http.Response into struct using json.Unmarshal

Tags: go

I'm calling a remote API and getting a JSON response back. I'm trying to convert the `*http.Response` into a struct that I defined. Everything i've tried so far has resulted in an empty struct. Here is my attempt with json.Unmarshal

```
type Summary struct {
   Created  string  `json:"created"`          
   High     float64 `json:"high"`             
   Low      float64 `json:"low"`              
}

func getSummary() {

   url := "http://myurl"

   resp, err := http.Get(url)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalln(err)
   }

   body, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
   if err2 != nil {
       panic(err.Error())
   }

   log.Printf("body = %v", string(body))
   //outputs: {"success":true,"message":"","result":["High":0.43600000,"Low":0.43003737],"Created":"2017-06-25T03:06:46.83"}]}

   var summary = new(Summary)
   err3 := json.Unmarshal(body, &summary)
   if err3 != nil {
       fmt.Println("whoops:", err3)
       //outputs: whoops: <nil> 
   }

   log.Printf("s = %v", summary)
   //outputs: s = &{{0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0  0}}


}
```

What am I doing wrong? The JSON tags in my struct match the json keys from the response exactly...

**edit**: here is the JSON returned from the API

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "''",
  "result": [
    {
      "High": 0.0135,
      "Low": 0.012,
      "Created": "2014-02-13T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

**edit**
i changed the struct to this but still not working

```
type Summary struct {
   Result struct {
       Created string  `json:"created"`
       High    float64 `json:"high"`
       Low     float64 `json:"low"`
   } 
 }
```

Comment: yea the program prints the `whoops` error. Using `%v` outputs the exact same

Comment: I added an update. Why is the output of `err3` = `<nil>` if the previous if statement requires that `eer3` is not nil?

Comment: `body` is not valid JSON. You have to remove the `%!(EXTRA string=` and the `)` in order to be able to use `json.Unmarshal` on it.

Comment: Additionally `Summary` is not the same shape as the JSON data anyway. You need to make it match the shape of the whole JSON object (after removing the portions mentioned above) in order to be able to unmarshal it.

Comment: I used %v as suggested to print the `body` and the formatting issue is corrected. Still trying to get the nested struct to work

Comment: please add the response JSON in the question.

Comment: The structure of the JSON does not match the Go type that you are decoding to. Try decoding to a struct { Result []Summary }

Comment: @Cerise Limon, that changed the output so its printing the values now but not the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your structure like this

```
type Summary struct {
  Sucess bool `json:"success"`
  Message string `json:"message"`
  Result []Result `json:"result"`
}

type Result struct {
   Created string  `json:"Created"`
   High    float64 `json:"High"`
   Low     float64 `json:"Low"`
}
```

Try this [link](https://play.golang.org/p/QV0gWdwSRN2)

Answer (score 2):

Its because you're trying to unmarshal an array into struct,
Use array instead of the Result struct

```
type Summary struct {
    Result []struct {
        Created string  `json:"created"`
        High    float64 `json:"high"`
        Low     float64 `json:"low"`
    }
}
```

Use this weblink to convert your JSON objects to Go Struct >> https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: That json to go converter is an awesome resource, thanks for sharing!